# Read CSS file contents from remote server using c# web api

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, httpclient

I am trying to read a css file contents from a remote server using HTTPClient. However, it gives garbage contents rather than actual file contents. Can someone please help what is missing?

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetAttachment2()
        {
            UriBuilder uriBuilder = new UriBuilder();
            uriBuilder.Scheme = "https";
            uriBuilder.Host = "xyz.com";

            var Path = "jwt/resources/autogenerated/mystyle.css";
            uriBuilder.Path = Path;

                HttpClientHandler clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler { ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; } };
                using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(clientHandler))
                {
                    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(uriBuilder.ToString());
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = Request?.Headers?.Authorization;
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("text/css"));
                    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
                    var content = await client.GetStringAsync(uriBuilder.Uri);
                }

            return Content(HttpStatusCode.OK, content);
        }
```

**Output:**
�\b"�\b"�\b"�\b something like this.

Comment: that code won't even compile

Answer (score 0):

You have declared your `content` content variable inside the using statement. Try

```
    var Path = "jwt/resources/autogenerated/mystyle.css";
    uriBuilder.Path = Path;
    string content;

    HttpClientHandler clientHandler = new HttpClientHandler { ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback = (sender, cert, chain, sslPolicyErrors) => { return true; } };
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(clientHandler))
    {
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(uriBuilder.ToString());
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = Request?.Headers?.Authorization;
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("text/css"));
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
        content = await client.GetStringAsync(uriBuilder.Uri);
    }

    return Content(HttpStatusCode.OK, content);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two issues to deal with.

First, you need to change the code to make it actually compile. You already have an answer that deals with that, although you could simply return from inside the using block. Whether that's a huge difference or not, remains debatable.

But anyway, the code could look like this:

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient(clientHandler))
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri(uriBuilder.ToString());
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = Request?.Headers?.Authorization;
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("text/css"));
    ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
    var content = await client.GetStringAsync(uriBuilder.Uri);
    return Content(HttpStatusCode.OK, content);
}
```

Be careful here because **you're really not supposed to use the HTTPClient like this**, it's not efficient at all to wrap it inside a using block, you want to keep one client instance available for all the calls you make. Make it a static variable instead, for example.

Your second issue with the garbage characters, that could be an encoding issue. I would check what kind of encoding you're using and maybe change the way you setup your client accordingly.